# Ant Design: Override text colour of Menu.Item

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'd like to override the text colour of a menu item in ant design.

```
 <Menu.Item key="home" style={{color: "#BFBFBF"}}>
     <Link to="/">Home</Link>
 </Menu.Item>
```

However, this doesn't work. I've also tried to override the style directly

```
.ant-menu-title-content { color: #BFBFBF; }
```

but this doesn't work either.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your custom CSS rules must be getting overridden somewhere else.

It works for me:

[image]

You might also want to try targeting the `ant-menu-item` class and/or putting `!important` after the `color` hex.